# Stream with recursive function in Elixir language

Tags: recursion, stream, elixir

In scala the code below works (I know it's weird, but I want to test stream concat with recursive functions)

```
def ones(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = 1 #:: ones(s)
ones(Stream.from(1)).take(10).toList
```

I wrote some elixir code that should be equivalent to the scala code and it hangs. How can I get the same effect as the above scala code?

```
defmodule Ones do
  def ones(s) do
    head = Stream.take(s, 1)
    Stream.concat(head, ones(s))
  end
end

Ones.ones(Stream.iterate(1, &(&1 + 1))) |> Enum.take(10) # hang
```

Comment: You didn't provide any condition to stop the recursion, that's why it hung.

I don't know about scala, but it looks like you only take 10 elements from stream, since streams are lazy so this is enough to stop.

Correct me if wrong, I'm just a beginner ;)

Comment: @nightire Above scala code is exactly same with elixir code, but one is work, others is not. I dont't know why two language has different behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `#::` operator in scala evaluates its right argument lazily. That's why you can construct "infinite" recursions like that and it still works out. In Elixir there is no notion of lazily evaluated arguments, so `ones(s)` always calls `ones(s)` at the end resulting in an infinite loop. In order to avoid that you'd need to use a `Stream` function that explicitly deals with lazy values to construct your result, for example `Stream.resource`.

Comment: Thx for your comment. I need it for make prime stream http://exercism.io/submissions/612742e25fc84703ba091138cbef18e9

Comment: `Stream.resource` should be sufficient for that